# Difference between $parent.find(selector) vs. $(selector, $parent)?

Tags: jquery

Is there any difference between the two? Would they ever yield different results?

```
$parent.find(selector)

vs. 

$(selector, $parent)
```

where $parent - a jQuery object.

Comment: The duplicate - claiming somewhat significant speed differences, and not disclosing implementation - does not seem correct wrt the documentation in the current answer. Not voting to close without further details. (Although  the performance differences might just be accounted for in overloading and creating a new [?] jQuery set.)

Comment: Turns out it's a duplicate, thanks for pointing that out! I'm closing it as a dup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the same thing.  When you pass in the optional context parameter to the `.find()` method, it's basically converted to `$(selector, $parent)`

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selector-context

> Internally, selector context is implemented with the .find() method,
>   so  $( "span", this ) is equivalent to  $( this ).find( "span" ).

So, no - it should never yield different results.